# Vector Spaces Help

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Which of the following are vector spaces?

- $\mathbb Z$, the set of all integers
- the set of all $2\times 2$ matrices
- $\mathbb R$, the set of real numbers
- set of all polynomials
- $\mathcal C[-1,1]$, the set of continuous functions on the closed interval $[-1,1]$

Comment: without any given operations on these sets its not meaningful to ask whether those sets are vector spaces or not

Comment: Well this is a question in my textbook and it's all it gives. I am sure 4th is a vector space though.

Comment: Then you should look for another textbook :) Question should be e.g. sth like: "Is the set of all $2\times 2$ matrices with compoentwise addition and componentwise multiplication an vectorspace over $\mathbb R$? "

Comment: Without such information the question just dont make sense

Comment: Either there is a "group header" for a set of problems there indicating the assumptions, or the author is just asking you to assume the use of ordinary addition and multiplication for making linear combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) No because scaling over $\mathbb{R}$ is not closed under scaling.

2) Yes

3) Yes

4) Yes if they are polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$.

5) Yes

Comment: could you please explain 2,3, and 5 please?

Comment: @user123204 Just follow the definition of vector space. Each of them follows.

Comment: If he would follow the definition of vector space he wont be able to answer this question because of missing information. See my comments to the question given above.

Comment: I quite agree, which means either the problem is written sloppily (which I see all too often in recent textbooks), the author simply expected the student to use ordinary arithmetic, or OP missed a statement header somewhere indicating the operations to apply.